# regression analysis or MANOVA or..?

Tags: regression, anova, manova

We have this data from 5 different treatment groups with a different sample sizes and need some help for analysis.

Participants were randomly assigned to a group and were exposed to a certain treatment. Evaluations were done in 3 points (pre treatment, post treatment(right after the treatment) and end treatment (at the end of procedure). The "procedure" itself doesn't affect the analysis but the length(time) of the procedure may.

What we wanted to evaluate is whether all the treatment shows the same efficacy at the end or not.

Some of the participant underwent two or three treatment; but different day and there was washout period. The study was not designed as repeated measurement.

I was going to do One-way anova, but maybe regression analysis or MANOVA would be more appropriate? I also thought randomized blocked design but the number of samples in a group are different..

Please help!